# Replace values in a pandas column based on dictionary/mapping of indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have the dictionary

```
dicts: {0: '1969',  1: '1971',  2: '76'}
```

I also have the following df:

```
    Start date      End Date
0       w              a
1       A              2
2       B             NaN
```

Now I want to put the dictionary in place of one DataFrame column

```
df = df.replace({'Start date': dicts})
```

Result: Nothing changed :(

Expected:

```
    Start date      End Date
0       1969           a
1       1971           2
2       76            NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a more appropriate option here would be to convert your dict to a Series and call `update`:

```
df['Start date'].update(pd.Series(dct))
df

  Start date End Date
0       1969        a
1       1971        2
2         76      NaN
```

`replace` will not work, because it requires the dictionary to contain {: }, but you've provided the indices instead. So, in a nutshell, to have `replace` working, you would need to do

```
dct2 = {df.at[i, 'Start date']: v for i, v in dct.items()}
df.replace({'Start date': dct2})

  Start date End Date
0       1969        a
1       1971        2
2         76      NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
#Creating Your DataFrame
d= {'Start Date': ['w','a','b'],'End Date': ['a',2,'Nan']}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

#Assigning Your Dict Column
dicts = {0: '1969',  1: '1971',  2: '76'}
df['Start Date']= pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicts, orient='index')
df
```

See the documentation of dictionary to dataframe here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html

Answer (score 1):

[`pd.DataFrame.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) replaces by value, not by index alignment. For the latter, one option is to [`pd.Index.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html) an index via a dictionary:

```
dicts = {0: '1969',  1: '1971',  2: '76'}
df['StartDate'] = df.index.map(dicts)

print(df)

  StartDate EndDate
0      1969       a
1      1971       2
2        76     NaN
```

If there are potentially *unmapped* indices, you can use [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with a series:

```
df['StartDate'] = pd.Series(df.index.map(dicts)).fillna(df['StartDate'])
```