# For Loop through an array to replace value in a dataframe

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am trying to use loop through ind_num to match the index value using iloc .. then replace the value next to the index value by looping through designation.

this is an example problem which closely reflect a project I am working on .. but I feel this example makes it easier for others to understand what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [['h', 'zero'], ['i', 'circle'], ['j', 'two'], ['k','square']] 
#goal is to replace 'circle' and 'square' with 'one' and 'three' respectively 


df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['letters', 'ind_name'])

print(df)

ind_num = [1, 3]

designation = ['one', 'three']


'''for x in ind_num
    for y in designation
        df.iloc[x][1]''' # not sure where to go from here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace values in a pandas column based on dictionary/mapping of indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054604/replace-values-in-a-pandas-column-based-on-dictionary-mapping-of-indices)

Comment: For the solution in the suggested duplicate, you can create a dic for replacements with `designation_dic = {ind_num[i]:designation[i] for i in range(len(ind_num))}`

Comment: But if really want to loop, taking into account that both `ind_number` and `designation` should have the same length: `for i in range(len(ind_num)): df.iloc[ind_num[i]][1] = designation[i]`

Comment: thank you for the help. I'm sure the answer is in here somewhere .. but my knowledge is not sophisticated enough to understand it ha

Comment: Try looking at [Pandas Dataframe, using iloc to replace last row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51645414/16653700).

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over each element of `ind_num` and then `designation`, you are going to end up iterating over all combinations (1 - 'one', 1 - 'three', 2 - 'one', 2 - 'three').

Because `ind_num` and `designation` should have the same length, you can simply do

```
for i in range(len(ind_num)):
    df.iloc[ind_num[i]][1] = designation[i]
```

Or, you can just generate a dictionary mapping index to updated value and use pandas' `update`:

```
designation_dic = {ind_num[i]:designation[i] for i in range(len(ind_num))}

df['ind_name'].update(pd.Series(designation_dic))
```

The first line just uses dictionary comprehension to produce `{1: 'one', 3: 'three'}`